# pyttsx3 module is not showing all installed voices

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, chatbot, pyttsx

I am using the pyttsx3 module.
I have the the Microsoft James voice installed and I can hear it when pressing the "preview voice" button in the windows speech settings.
However when I try to view all the voices, only "Microsoft David Desktop - English (United States)" and "Microsoft Zira Desktop - English (United States)" come up.

Why doesn't the Microsoft James voice show up ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56730889/pyttsx-isn-t-showing-installed-languages-on-windows-10

Answer (score 3):

I could solve it by exporting the Tokens from the 64 Bit registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech_OneCore\Voices\Tokens
```

into a REG file and importing to the 32 Bit registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\SPEECH\Voices\Tokens
```

as well as the 64 Bit registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SPEECH\Voices\Tokens
```

This requires search/replace editing in a text editor. Just do it if you're familiar with changing the Registry.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what needs to be searched/replaced in a text editor, for those who are not familiar? I'm _guessing_ it's the registry paths...

Comment: You search for the text of code block 1 and replace by code block 2, then import that. Then search for the text in code block 2 and replace by code block 3, then import that as well.

Answer (score 1):

First press the "windows" key and "R" key simultaneously A run window should pop up. Click on the run box and type "regedit" and click enter, click "yes" and proceed. A registry editor should pop up. Now continue at your own risk(make a registry backup, I don't know what it is just search it) . Double click on "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE", then "SOFTWARE " --> "MICROSOFT " sroll down then "SPEECH SERVER" --> "v11.0" now you should see "Voices".

Right click on "Voices" and you should see "Export". Then save the file somwhere you know(any filename) Go to the location where you saved it then right click the file Now close the registry editor

Then click on "Open with" --> Notepad After that click "Ctrl" + "H" A replace window should pop up In "Find what" type "Speech Server\v11.0" In "replace with" type "Speech" Then click replace all Then save and close the file Then open the same file with "Registry Editor" Click yes on both pop ups

press the "windows" key and "R" key simultaneously A run window should pop up. Click on the run box and type "regedit" and click enter, click "yes" and proceed. A registry editor should pop up.

Now you would be seeing "Voices" If you look a little higher up you should see "Speech Server" And just on top of that is "Speech" Open "Speech " by double clicking it Under "Voices" and "Tokens" you should see your newly installed voice.

Now scroll down until you see "Wow6432Node" Open that then, Open MICROSOFT " sroll down then "SPEECH SERVER" --> "v11.0" now you should see "Voices".

Right click on "Voices" and you should see "Export". Then save the file somwhere you know(any filename) Go to the location where you saved it then right click the file Now close the registry editor

Then click on "Open with" --> Notepad After that click "Ctrl" + "H" A replace window should pop up In "Find what" type "Speech Server\v11.0" In "replace with" type "Speech" Then click replace all Then save and close the file Then open the same file with "Registry Editor" Click yes on both pop ups Then click ok Now press the "windows" key and "R" key simultaneously A run window should pop up. Click on the run box and type "regedit" and click enter, click "yes" and proceed. A registry editor should pop up.

Now you would be seeing "Voices" If you look a little higher up you should see "Speech Server" And just on top of that is "Speech" Open "Speech " by double clicking it Under "Voices" and "Tokens" you should see your newly installed voice. Now, you are ready now test your code to check if it works correctly If you have any problems with code please tell here

Comment: Just out of curiosity, you got a post with the letter-by-letter-identical content deleted by a moderator (@MartijnPieters). The reason for the deletion was explained to you, wasn't it? How can you have incorporated that into your post without changing anything?

Comment: This was very hard to follow and has lots of grammatical errors; I gave up in the end.