# pyttsx3 is not changing voices an i think its because i use google colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyttsx3

i Use google colab and pyttsx3 is not changing voices
i also want to know how to add custom voices if possible

```
sound_engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = sound_engine.getProperty("voices")
sound_engine.set_property("voice", voices[1].id)
sound_engine.setProperty("rate", 150)
```

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44858120/how-to-change-the-voice-in-pyttsx3) to see how to list available `pyttsx3` voices and how to select the one you want.

Comment: Do you have an error message or any other feedback from the script?

Comment: no when i change voices it simply does not work
there is no error